# Flutter Material to Cupertino transformation issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I am working on a project which is almost 80% done. All my project is done on Material design. Now I am trying to move Cupertino UI theme for Android and IOS both.

As I am trying to migrate from Material design to Cupertino UI I am facing lots of problems especially in the below areas..

> 1. **TextFormField**: I am not able to find **TextFormField** in Cupertino design to use with forms...
> 2. **Validator**: How to valide **CupertinoTextField** as there is no validator method
> 3. App Drawer: Right now I have App Drawer. As I am moving to Cuprtino UI design for both IOS and Android should I drop the App Drawer?
> 4. How can I give the width of the CupertinoButton ?
> 5. ListTitle is throwing exception when I am trying to migrate to Cuprtio. The exception is "The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was: ListTitle"

Also, How can I mix a non Cuprtino widget on inside CupertinoPageScaffold page?

Thanks for your time

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: I have added more details...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> 1. **TextFormField**: I am not able to find **TextFormField** in Cupertino design to use with forms...
> 2. **Validator**: How to valide **CupertinoTextField** as there is no validator method

There's no `TextField` with validation & form methods in Cupertino. In iOS development, you would write your own form validation code and call them accordingly. It is no exception in Flutter as well.
One typical approach would be creating an inner `_FormData` class to store your `TextEditingController` for every `CupertinoTextField`, then validate them in your `CupertinoButton`'s `onPressed` callback.

> 3. App Drawer: Right now I have App Drawer. As I am moving to Cuprtino UI design for both IOS and Android should I drop the App Drawer?

Again, `Drawer` widget only exists in Material design. All drawers that you might be seeing in various iOS apps in the market are custom `UIView`s made by 3rd party providers. [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/drawers/) clearly stated that:

> **Avoid using drawers.** Drawers are seldom used in modern apps and their use is discouraged. Panels, popovers, sidebars, and split views are preferred for displaying supplementary window content.

You might want to consider using `CupertinoPageScaffold` or `CupertinoTabScaffold`, depending on your design requirements.

> 4. How can I give the width of the CupertinoButton ?

You can wrap your `CupertinoButton` with `Container`, `SizedBox` or `FractionallySizedBox`.

```
Container(
    width: 300 // or whatever width you want,
    child: CupertinoButton(
        child: Text('Submit'),
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onPressed: () {
            // Write your callback here
        },
    ),
)
```

or

```
SizedBox(
    width: 300 // or whatever you want,
    child: CupertinoButton(
        child: Text('Submit'),
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onPressed: () {
            // Write your callback here
        },
    ),
)
```

or

```
FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.5 // or whatever you want,
    child: CupertinoButton(
        child: Text('Submit'),
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onPressed: () {
            // Write your callback here
        },
    ),
)
```

In general, `Container` should do the trick. If you wrap your `CupertinoButton` in a `Flex` widget (such as `ListView`, `Column`), you might want to use `SizedBox` or `FractionallySizedBox`. You may refer to API documentation of [`SizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) and [`FractionallySizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html)

> 5. ListTitle is throwing exception when I am trying to migrate to Cuprtio. The exception is "The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was: ListTitle"

As the error log says:

> In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material Widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, **many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them**.
>   To introduce a Material widget, you can either **directly include one**, or **use a widget that contains Material itself**, such as a `Card`, `Dialog`, `Drawer`, or `Scaffold`.

I guess you are trying to use `ListTile` (which is a Material widget) in a `CupertinoPageScaffold` or `CupertinoTabView`, which are obviously Cupertino widgets. This is how I solved it:

```
Material(
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: ListTile(
        ...
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ken Tan for taking time and explain it very well.

Comment: The mentioned Drawer discouragement refers to Panels, Popovers, Sidebars and Split Views all of which are demonstrated on a macOS app's UI, but my immediate question is how about iOS? I doubt a regular iOS app has enough screen space for that.

Comment: @Kaspi iOS design guidelines are pretty much the same with macOS, however I have seen a growing number of iOS apps using a third party drawer UI. I think that developers who worked on cross-platform apps were slowly abandoning the iOS guidelines and went for Material instead.